# What is the most secure key expansion routine?

Tags: keys, algorithm-design, stream-cipher

I am looking at G now, but is there a better, (in terms of security and speed), means by which a byte array can be expanded that doesn't involve another cipher, just a simple algorithm?

I need to expand 1024 bytes to 4096 for use in a stream cipher, and speed is less important than overall distribution of entropy. I am also trying to find something that is strictly algorithmic, that doesn't employ hashing or another cipher. Any thoughts/recommendations?

Comment: Yes, a key expansion 'function' that does not use a block cipher, like the key scheduler in Rijndael that uses Rot, SubByte etc..

Comment: What will you use it for? The key expansion in Rijndael is very simple and not good for anything that expects a random key. [HKDF Expand](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869#section-2.3) is a good choice for many uses, but it needs a hash function.

Comment: Use a hash function like Keccak?

Comment: @Otus & Richie Frame -No hash function, something self-contained, a function. As I said I was looking at G, and Twofish is interesting, (generates part of the S-box based on the key), but, is there an algorithm that is considered 'most secure' in terms of entropy output?

Comment: Well, "most secure" is to use a [tag:kdf], which normally means using at least a block cipher or hash function. However, depending on what you use the derived key for, something simpler could be secure enough.

Comment: Key expansion for a stream cipher I'm writing. Array is used to generate key material, and some other stuff..

Comment: The stream cipher should have sufficient diffusion that every bit of output depends on every bit of state for it to be secure. So even concatenating zero bytes may be sufficient. However, the specifics depend on the cipher. ([Don't roll your own](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) bears repeating but I'm going to assume yours is for fun.)

Comment: Yes, just for fun.. I just want to examine the subject more deeply, (for now). Out of say, the AES finalists, is there any that strike you as having a more sophisticated key expansion routine than the others?

Comment: @John You could take a look at sosemanuk, which uses serpent as key expansion.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I haven't heard of that one.. I'll look through the code tomorrow. I'll also take another look at Serpent.. thanks

Comment: A hash function *is* a function. I don't think your expectations are very clear.

Comment: A function or method in a programmatic sense; A group of instructions that perform a specific task, but not a module or a class or an implementation of a specific cryptographic entity, like SHA. Like the key scheduler in Rijndael, (but that is too weak).

Comment: A hash function *is* a function or method in a programmatic sense. It accepts an input, performs some bounded amount computation, and returns an output. What are the actual criteria you're looking for?

Comment: @Stephen Touset -I guess more specifically, something simpler than using a hash, but complex enough to create expanded key material.. (because as noted by Otus, it should be strong but, whitening within the actual transform provides most of the diffusion). So of Twofish, Camellia, Serpent etc.. which contains the key expansion routine that produces the most entropic output and is best used as a stretching method? They are all based on various mathematical formulae, is one of those considered superior to the rest?

Comment: No key expansion (nor any computable function) can return a value with more entropy than what is input. The "best" you can accomplish (for some definition of the term) to is distribute the entropy evenly across the entire output.

Comment: @Stephen Touset -Not exactly. Some expansion routines employ randomizing tables deriving the indices from the initial value and than perform a manipulation of some kind. But yes, distributing the entropy across a wider plane, while adding entropy from a table is probably the right way to go.

Comment: I don't care how a function tries to do it. There's no computable way to take a number with $n$ bits of entropy and deterministically produce a result with $n+k$ bits of entropy where $k>0$. If there was, we'd could trivially implement truly random number generators in software.

Comment: New information is added though.. Consider; I use the last 10 bits from a uint in that input state array as the secret indice to a 1024 member uint array of non-linear values. I combine the two via some set of shifts and modular addition. I have now added information to the original state..

Comment: But you are right (if the table is known), than the output is equally predictable.. If the table is not known..

Comment: ..you have another source of entropy, but that's circular. Ok, so that aside, is there a method that distributes entropy better than the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities here, depending on the particulars of where exactly you will use it.

1. Your use case may require a random looking derived key, where the 1024 bytes of entropy have been distributed evenly over all the bytes of the final key. In that case there's no avoiding a key derivation function. You will have to use either a block cipher, a hash function, or something equally complex.
2. Your use of it in a stream cipher may not care at all, if the entropy will be subsequently diffused over the state anyway (maybe with extra initial rounds). In that case you may as well just set the rest of the bytes to zero, or perhaps concatenate four copies of the original key to increase the speed of initial diffusion.
3. The second point above may be true, but your cipher may have internal symmetries that could make certain bits or bytes "cancel out". In that case you may have to make sure the initial configuration does not lead to weaknesses due to that symmetry.
4. You may have some sort of security proof or reduction for the structure of the cipher, like a Feistel network has, for example. That could put requirements on the key, e.g. that certain parts have to differ. HMAC is an example where simply padding the key with two different bit patterns was sufficient for proofs.

In the end, the main guidance I would give out is to look at what other *stream ciphers* are doing. The [eSTREAM winners](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) would be a decent starting place.

Comment: Thanks Otus.. I ended up going with HMAC/HKDF-Expand, (and more realistic state sizes).